# React js: How to sort item from API data by ascending and descending

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data **from** an **API**, which includes information about **countries**. I want to sort the countries by ascending and descending from **onClick** according their names. For now the order of name's output is in **alphabetical** order(A-Z). I want to sort it to **Z-A** from onClick in the **name** in **Header** component. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Here isthe component I'm fetching data: useCountries

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function useCountries(search: string) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [savedCountries, setSavedCountries] = useState([])
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setData(result)
        setSavedCountries(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('error'))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const result = [...savedCountries].filter((item: any) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    )
    setData(result)
  }, [search, savedCountries])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return [data]
}
```

Header component

```
import React from 'react'

import './Header.scss'

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <ul className="HeadtableRow">
        <li>Flag</li>
        <li>Name</li>  {/* onClick must work from here */}
        <li>Language</li>
        <li>Population</li>
        <li>Region</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In MainTable I'm mapping through fetched data

```
import React from 'react'

import Header from '../Header'
import TableRow from '../TableRow'

import './mainTable.scss'

export default function MainTable({ countries }: any) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <table className="table">
        <tbody className="tableBody">
          {countries &&
            countries.map((country?: any) => (
              <TableRow
                key={country.name}
                flagUrl={country.flag}
                countryName={country.name}
                languages={country.languages}
                population={country.population}
                region={country.region}
              />
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give you an answer specific to your code (In your code you don't use any click handler -or- sort method). This is more a freelancer mission to give you an "as is" solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

**Related Q / articles:**

- [React : How to sort data in asc and desc in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239785/react-how-to-sort-data-in-asc-and-desc-in-reactjs)
- [How to toggle on Order in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283338/how-to-toggle-on-order-in-reactjs)
- [How to make a table in ReactJS sortable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375407/how-to-make-a-table-in-reactjs-sortable/44375705)
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/sortable-tables-react/

**API**

If your API support **sorting** you could use this =>
Call like `/countries?sort_by=asc(name)`

**Hello world**

**"Hello World"** example (I use **lodash** [order_by method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy)). You could take this basic code forward (Add an active class, Use API instead of static data, handle errors, handle [immutable data](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper), and so on).

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/* Data */
const users = [{name: "Bob", id: 1}, {name: "Abie", id: 2}, {name: "Michael", id: 3}, {name: "Zoie", id: 4}, {name: "Omer", id: 5}];

function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function UserList(props) {  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(props.users);

  function sortUsersByAsc() {
    const orderBy = _.orderBy(users, ['name'], ['asc']);
    setUsers(orderBy);
  }
  
   function sortUsersByDesc() {
    const orderBy = _.orderBy(users, ['name'], ['desc']);
    setUsers(orderBy);
  }
  
  const listItems = users.map((user) =>
    <ListItem key={user.id.toString()}
     value={user.name} />
    );
     return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {listItems}
        </ul>       
        <button onClick={() => sortUsersByAsc()}>Sort List By <b>A to Z</b> &darr;</button> 
        <br/><br/>
        <button onClick={() => sortUsersByDesc()}>Sort List By <b>Z to A</b> &uarr;</button>
       </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserList users={users} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue; color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**NPM package**

**One more idea is to use a package like ("build-in" sorting features):**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table